# What are cookies and sessions, and how do they relate to each other?

Tags: javascript, php, session, cookies

I am trying to understand cookies and sessions professionally.
I know that when a browser connects to a server, the server "asks" the browser to "paste" a cookie with "phpsessid" in the client browser cookies folder.

Now that we have the "phpsessid", if the client enters the server the browser sends to the server the "phpsessid" and the server takes a look at the tmp folder and if we have a match it loads back every data the user has for this client, but I am kinda confused with the process.

I will be thankful if some one can help me understand those processes of creating a session and cookies - what is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: It seems you already know what's happening. Which specific part would you like to be enlightened on? The HTTP/cookie part, or how PHP loads the session store?

Comment: The cookie that the browser is saving with the phpsessid, is this the phpsessid to identify the client for creating sessions and cookies?

Comment: The cookie the browser has contains the php session id, which tells the server "hey I know this chap", the server then grabs the session data (from /tmp/ for example) and restores the user $_SESSION

Comment: Yes i know that, but i am asking, is this "phpsessid" is using to identify the client before creating sessions and cookies, is this phpsessid is including inside the cookie data and the client computer and inside the session file at the server tmp folder?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Let's go through this:

**[Cookies](http://il.php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)** and **[sessions](http://il.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)** are both ways to preserve the application's state between different requests the browser makes. It's thanks to them that, for instance, you don't need to log in every time you request a page on **[StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)**.

### Cookies

Cookies are small bits of data, (maximum of 4KB long), which hold data in a key=value pairs:

```
name=value; name2=value2
```

These are set either by **[JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie)**, or via the server using an **[HTTP header](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)**.

Cookies have an expiry datetime set, example using HTTP headers:

```
Set-Cookie: name2=value2; Expires=Wed, 19 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT
```

Which would cause the browser to set a cookie named `name2` with a value of `value2`, which would expire in about 9 years.

Cookies are considered **highly insecure** because the user can easily manipulate their content. That's why you should **always validate cookie data**. Don't assume what you get from a cookie is necessarily what you expect.

Cookies are usually used to preserve login state, where a username and a special hash are sent from the browser, and the server checks them against the database to approve access.

Cookies are also often used in **sessions** creation.

### Sessions

Sessions are slightly different. Each user gets a **session ID**, which is sent back to the server for validation either by **cookie** or by **GET variable**.

Sessions are usually short-lived, which makes them ideal in saving temporary state between applications. Sessions also expire once the user closes the browser.

Sessions are considered more secure than cookies because the variables themselves are kept on the **server**. Here's how it works:

1. Server opens a session (sets a cookie via HTTP header)
2. Server sets a session variable.
3. Client changes page
4. Client sends all cookies, along with the session ID from step 1.
5. Server reads session ID from cookie.
6. Server matches session ID from a list in a database (or memory etc).
7. Server finds a match, reads variables which are now available on `$_SESSION` superglobal.

If PHP does not find a match, it will start a new session, and repeat the steps from 1-7.

You can store sensitive information on a session because it is kept on the server, but be aware that the session ID can still be stolen if the user, let's say, logged in over an insecure WiFi. (An attacker can sniff the cookies, and set it as its own, he won't see the variables themselves, but the server will identify the attacker as the user).

---

That's the gist of it. You can learn more on the PHP manual on both subjects.

Comment: So does that mean cookies have to turned on in order for sessions to work?

Comment: @Edmund: On most cases, yes. You can, however, set it so that session IDs are transmitted via GET variable (which would mean that the session_id would need to be appended to every page (`hello.php?sid=cbe709ac7bed98f7ecb89713`)

Comment: What exactly means close browser on Android or iPhone devices? stop app? turn off device? close all tabs and exit? etc

Comment: @Vandervals Based on the memory architecture on those devices, I'd wager stop app should do the trick.

Comment: "Sessions also expire once the user closes the browser ", Won't that will make us relogin everytime?

Comment: @SurajJain It would, if it weren't for "remember me" cookies, that persist longer.

Comment: Is it not the case, that for routing or getting access to protected sensitive information, the user has to validate his credentials once again? Or can he safely navigate everywhere as long as that sessionID / Cookie is stored in his browser?

Comment: other question: WHen the user closes the browser, how does the server get notified by this event so that the server deletes this session ID? or does it expire automatically after some time?

Comment: Looking at this in 2021 and I was confused why you said it would be active for 9 more years

Comment: `username and a special hash are sent from the browser, and the server checks them against the database to approve access` Don't do this! Hashing should ALWAYS be done on the server side. Even if you're hashing on the client side, hash it again on server side.