# How to create lifetime session in yii2

Tags: php, session, yii, yii2

I have started using Yii2 basic  and need to store session information. I already know that in Yii2 basic, this should be done using sessions like

```
$session = Yii::$app->session;
$session->open();
$_SESSION["a_id"] = $id;
$_SESSION["w_auth"] = "true";
```

**The problem with this is that every time the browser is closed my session expire**
Is there anyway to keep session alive or set session destroy so even I close the browser and open it again. It will not  ask me again to put my username or password.I need to do this in the YII2 Basic .

Comment: In advanced template it is already implemented, you can refer that. Yii2 uses cookie based login to achieve that.

Comment: i am used yii2 basic app

Comment: it is possible but dont do that ! use cookies instead

Answer (score 1):

session cookies set expire time after 7 days
`

```
'components' => [
    'session' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\Session',
        'cookieParams' => ['lifetime' => 7 * 24 *60 * 60]
    ],
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cookies for this.
Cookies are info kept in your browser.
Here is how to do in yii2:

```
$cookies = Yii::$app->response->cookies;

// add a new cookie to the response to be sent
$cookies->add(new \yii\web\Cookie([
            'name' => 'a_id',
            'value' => $id,
]));
```

Add the above cookie when you login and then use it this way in your actions:

```
$cookies = Yii::$app->response->cookies;

$a_id = $cookies->getValue('a_id');

if($a_id !== null) {
    // user is logged in
}
```

Note: What is kept in the cookie of your browser is not your actual info, but the session id and this is sent when you reopen your browser and restores your session by this id. Your actual info is kept in your session(in the server). This how yii 2 cookies work.

### References

- [What are cookies and sessions, and how do they relate to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142882/what-are-cookies-and-sessions-and-how-do-they-relate-to-each-other)
- [Cookies vs. sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253633/cookies-vs-sessions)