# Can plugins read your cookies?

Tags: cookies, plugins, web

For example, if a website stores your username and passwords in cookies when you select the "keep me sign in" option, can plugins read the cookies when you access the website?

Answer (score 1):

Browser plugins like [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?utm_source=inline-install-disabled) can read cookies from the website you're visiting. Cookies are basically small text files containing a small amount of information, for example preferences, session cookies and such.

Let's take a look into the source from the plugin i've mentioned in my answer. The source contains a lot of code to get all cookies and match the URL with the specific cookie. Also I found this in the source: `chrome.cookies.getAll()`. This function can read all the cookies stored in your browser.

Take a look at the snippet i've copied from the source:

```
chrome.cookies.getAll({}, function(cookieL) {
    for (var x = 0; x < cookieL.length; x++) {
        var cCookie = cookieL[x];
        if (filterMatchesCookie(filterURL, cCookie.name, cCookie.domain, cCookie.value)) {
            var cUrl = (cCookie.secure) ? "https://" : "http://" + cCookie.domain + cCookie.path;
            deleteCookie(cUrl, cCookie.name, cCookie.storeId, cCookie)
        }
    }
});
```

So to answer your question: yes, plugins can read your cookies.

Comment: So if plugins can read our cookies then how is it safe for websites to store our passwords in cookies?

Comment: @frosty Websites should **never** store passwords in cookies.

Comment: But wouldn't they have to if they have the "keep you sign in" option? As far as I know SESSIONS expire when you close your browser.

Comment: @frosty I think you're mistaking tokens with passwords. Websites who offer `keep me signed in` options, make cookies with (encrypted) tokens.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: And if they make cookies with tokens, does that mean plugins can't see the password?

Comment: @frosty Passwords should be stored **encrypted** in anytime, where no one can see them, not in cookies, not in plain text files, not in your browser's localstorage, but safe in a database. Tokens is just a string of random characters, identifying the user. However someone can steal tokens and uses yours. If a website has a decent security, it can identify the real user using the token cookies. I suggest you to read this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142882/how-do-cookies-and-sessions-work

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are data, so It depends on who wrote the plugin.

Didn't read it all but it look's like a good intro.

http://anantgarg.com/2012/02/18/busting-the-cookies-and-privacy-myth/